# User Defined Function with UNLOAD command

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to use a [Python] User Defined Function inside an UNLOAD to S3 command?

```
unload (
  'select * temp_table'
  )
  to f_my_filename_function()
  ACCESS_KEY_ID ''
  SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ''
  delimiter as ','
;
```

Use case is to have a dynamic, custom filename prefix.

Comment: no - but a nice idea! would solve some tricky issues. would be great if AWS was to consider enabling UDF type functionality for COPY and LOAD.

Comment: @JonScott Thanks. Would be pretty interesting. I wonder if it's possible. I guess an obvious solution is to use an event lambda/watcher on the s3 bucket, and handle the files when created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

You could use a UDF in the `SELECT` portion, but a UDF cannot be used in other ways.